# C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex

Tags: c++, algorithm, compiler-errors, c++17

I tried to write a function that would call back with every permutation of size n:

```
template<typename F>
void permutationsCallback(int n, F f) {
    if (n == 1) {
        f(std::vector<int>{0});
    }
    else {
        permutationsCallback(n - 1, [n, &f](std::vector<int> p) {
            p.emplace_back(n - 1);
            f(p);
            while (--p.back() >= 0) {
                for (int k = 0; k < n - 1; k++) {
                    p[k] += p[k] == p.back();
                }
                f(p);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

(For example I want `permutationsCallback(3, f)` to call `f({0,1,2}`, `f({0,2,1})`, `f({1,2,0})`, `f({1,0,2})`, `f({2,0,1})`, `f({2,1,0})`.)

but on compilation with MCSV I get error

> fatal error C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex

How can I fix this?

Comment: Note that even once you fix the infinite recursion, this will be an *insanely* inefficient way to visit all permutations, due to the allocation and copying overhead.

Comment: @Sneftel Interesting. I would have thought n copies and reallocations (assuming client's `f` receives its argument by reference) would amount to asymptotic nothingness in comparison to the number of callbacks. What algorithm would you recommend instead?

Comment: There’s a few algorithms for generating all permutations, notably Heap’s Algorithm... it depends on whether you need them in a particular order. The common feature of all of these is that they permute in-place rather than allocating anew for each permutation. In contrast, the way you pass the vectors in your code actually ensures that there will be n allocations per permutation generated.

Comment: @Sneftel I don't think `permutationsCallback(n, [](const std::vector<int>&){})` would make n allocations per permutation generated. I think it would copy&reallocate once for every n permutations generated (or O(1) bytes per permutation generated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an infinite recursion inside the template.
Even if you know the else-block won't be called at runtime, at compile time, the compiler needs to know what code would have gone into the else block, endlessly.

You can for example consider making `n` a template parameter instead, and implement the 0 case, like MSVC explains on their page for this error message:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1202?view=msvc-160

For reference from link above:

```cpp
// C1202b.cpp
// compile with: /c
template<int n>
class Factorial : public Factorial<n-1> {
public:
   operator int () {
      return Factorial <n-1>::operator int () * n;
   }
};

template <>
class Factorial<0> {
public:
   operator int () {
      return 1;
   }
};

Factorial<7> facSeven;
```